# Uncertainly importing modules with Python

Tags: design-patterns, python

I'm developing a module that should be able to interact with other modules such as numpy or PIL. To accept parameters and test if, for example, a parameter is an `numpy.ndarray`, I'd need to import numpy first.

What I used to do on previous projects is

```python
numpy_exists = True
try:
    import numpy as np
except:
    numpy_exists = False
```

Then, when accepting parameters that **could** be of type `<type numpy.ndarray>` I checked it like that:

```python
    if numpy_exists and type(param) == np.ndarray:
        # ...
```

Now, it works, but it feels very weak because (personally) I look at the statement and the only thing I see is the `NameError` this code could raise. Of course, it doesn't raise the error, but code like that makes me feel awkward when looking at it.

Is this a good way to handle the problem? Is there a better one?

Comment: What I don't understand is why would be missing a package that your module needs. I mean, if your module needs numpy in order to interact with it, just add required packages in the project's setup.py file.

Comment: The catch is that my module does not *need* numpy. It *can* interact with numpy, if it helps the user's convenience. For example, the user can pass a file stream (of an image, for example) or a numpy array that represents a cv2 image. Then if the user does not want to have cv2 and numpy involved, they don't have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this is generally fine. But from a design standpoint, I'd probably solve it by moving the type checking for parameters in my own function (or even into a decorator, which looks much nicer). Then you can provide two different functions, depending on whether numpy exists or not, and don't even incur any speed cost. E.g:

```
def typecheck_without_numpy(...):
    ...

def typecheck_with_numpy(...):
    ...

try: 
    import numpy
    typecheck = typecheck_with_numpy
except ImportError:
    typecheck =  typecheck_without_numpy


def some_function(x):
    typecheck(x)
```

Of course, you can rename `typecheck` to something like `type_check_and_cast` and then either make it convert x to something your function can handle, or raise a `TypeError`. This way, your code isn't littered by type checks, and as I said, you could move the typecheck into a decorator, so your functions would look something like

```
@typecheck
def some_function(x):
   ...
```

Comment: Must admit this looks much cleaner like you did it. Thanks.